# Synchronisation mechanism in Flutter

Tags: flutter, synchronization, android-workmanager

I’m looking for the best solution to implement an offline-first app and syncing mechanism.
There are a lot of databases to choose from (I will probably go with Hive). However, I’m wondering what’s the best way to manage syncing in Flutter?

For Android Native, for managing syncing I was using `Jetpack Work Manager`  Every time I wanted to Post something to network, I enqueued Worker, and if the app was offline, the Android OS was managing to send that data itself.
Also, I could trigger downloading updates only when a user is connected to wifi, etc.

I’m wondering if there are similar solutions in Flutter world or maybe there is a better way to do that in Flutter that I'm not aware of?

I found only that package https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager, but seems like it’s well not supported anymore.